# My Link tag from react-router doesn't change my page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router

I have the following structure:

```
<CategoryRecipesList>
  <Title> Recipes for {this.props.category} </Title>
  <Mesh> You can also click on : {categoryList.map(el => <Link to={'categories/' + el}>{el}</Link>} </Mesh>

  <Grid>
   recipes.map((s, i) => <Card {...s}/>)
  </Grid>
</CategoryRecipesList>
```

I have a constructor function on the CategoryList component that fetches `recipes` list according to a `category` param.

When I click on the `<Link/>` tag, the title and the url update but not the `<Card>`s in the grid.

Does anyone has any clue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I needed to take in consideration that the cards in the grid depends on the props in the parent component (). So if I change the url from a click on the `<Mesh/>`, I need to use `ComponentWillReceiveProps(newProps)` method, compare if this.props.category has change by comparing (`this.props.category` and `newProps.category`). If so, I need to fetch the new cards to be displayed accurately. Works well now.

In the `<CategoryRecipesList>`component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.params.category_type !== nextProps.params.category_type) {
      this.category = nextProps.params.category_type
      this.props.fetchRecipesByDevice(this.category)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking at [Update Blocking](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/dealing-with-update-blocking). Try wrapping the Card component with [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter%20%22withRouter).

```
export default withRouter(Card)
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question to have a more explicit explanation of my struggle.

Comment: @StanAmsellem I updated my answer. Try wrapping the _Card_ component.

Comment: @StanAmsellem please put your code in Plunkr or something similar. Please also note that "it doesn't work" is a highly unconstructive reply; has it broken previously working items? What does the console say? Etc.

Comment: yes you're right @WillStone, it was a bit vague, I was frustrated to try different ways and not find the solution. Sorry if that a bit harsh :) and thanks for make me discovering withRouter() method and take the chance to dig into the recent release of react-router

Comment: @StanAmsellem no problem. Can you please post the solution if you've found one? In case somebody ends up here from a web search.

Comment: Just updated my answer @WillStone. Hope it will help.